# Can I simplify this script that simply adds a script to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I used this as a starting point, but realize it depend upon a div being present.

Curious as to wether or not I can just use `appendChild` to append the script directly to document.body?

```
// loads a script using the DOM and an optional argument to bust the cache
function loadScript(path, bust) {
  console.log("Loading | " + path + " | " + bust)
  const ref = document.getElementsByTagName( 'div' )[ 0 ];
  const script = document.createElement( 'script' );
  if(bust){
    path = path + '?cache_buster=' + bust;
  }
  script.src = path;
  ref.parentNode.insertBefore( script, ref );
}
```

**Per Answer**

```
// loads a script using document.body and an optional argument to bust the cache
function loadScript(path, bust) {
  if(bust){
    path = path + '?cache_buster=' + bust;
  }
  document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = path;
  console.log("Loading | " + path + " | ");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Curious as to wether or not I can just use appendChild to append the script directly to `document.body`?

Sure you could. As long as the script doesn't depend on its location in the DOM (eg, as long as it doesn't reference `document.currentScript` to look around nearby elements), the location of a `<script>` tag is irrelevant.

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src = path;
```

You don't even need the `<body>` to exist (or even the `<head>`, in certain unusual circumstances) - you can insert a `<script>` wherever you like.